# In Summary report csv,how to add Average, Min and Max when running from console

Tags: jmeter

When I run the test in GUI, i see the Average, Min, Max in GUI. But when I run in console, is there a way to add these to the csv file?

Answer (score 1):

These values are being **calculated** so you will be able to see the values only when you open .jtl results file after test finishes in the listener of your choice, i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) or [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report).

If you want to see the interim statistics while your test is being executed you have the following choices:

1. JMeter Summarizer output. JMeter reports some numbers into stdout while your test is being running

   [image: JMeter Summarizer]
2. You can get some extended information if you run your JMeter test using Taurus tool as a wrapper

   [image: JMeter Taurus]

   Both console and web interface options are available, in order to see current test execution stats in browser start your test like:

   ```
   bzt yourtest.jmx -report
   ```

   [image: JMeter Taurus Web Report]
3. And finally you can use [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) to send your results into database, message queue or web service and use custom plotting application to print out either raw or parsed statistics, here you are limited only by your fantasy:

   [image: JMeter Grafana]

   More information:

   - [JMeter: Real Time Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
   - [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter produces some basic fields/result_field. JMeter doesn't create everything you see in different types of Listeners.

You can give this a try.

Create a plan
Generate atleast 100 samples (As large amount of data is required for some listeners), using a single sampler (request)
Use as many Listeners as you want of different types (say 15 types of listeners)
Run the plan....
Now in the filename field of all the listeners give series of names of files like a1.jtl a2.jtl

and so on....

see the screen shot

[image]

enter image description here

Now again run the plan. Go to the files and open them in some good editors like notepad++.

For your surprise you will find the same data in all the files irrespective of the type of listener generating the file.

Crux of the matter is : JMeter gathers only handful of information from the run, the rest information which is shown in different Listeners is **COMPUTED** by the JMeter.

So you can read the *.jtl file into any of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter, the new way since 3.0 to have results is to use the Web report generated at end of test:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html